# Регулярные выражения форматирование строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Хочу отформатировать строку:

> about 90 percent of all children attend public school, which is free
>   ... the other 10 percent go I private schools,Which often include
>   religious education.

и получить на выходе такую строку:

> About 90 percent of all children attend public school, which is
>   free... The other 10 percent go I private schools, which often include
>   religious education.

Вышло заменить первую букву в выражении на большую, дальше не могу разобраться.
Код:

```
private static final String STRING = "about 90 percent of all children attend public school, which is free ... the other 10 percent go I private schools,Which often include religious education.";

private static final String REGEX = "(?:^| )^[a-z]";

public static void main(String[] args){
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(STRING);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()){
        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, matcher.group().toUpperCase());
    }
    matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
    System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
}
```

Comment: Объясните что на что по какому алгоритму нужно заменить.

Comment: @Эникейщик, по факту строку нужно просто отредактировать. 1) Большая буква после точки, все остальные прописными. 2) Убрать пробелы перед разделительными знаками(добавить после).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного разобравшись написал нужный функционал. Написано каряво, поэтому буду рад если укажите как можно упростить и оптимизировать код.

```
private static final String COMA_REGEX = "\\s*,\\s*";
private static final String DOT_REGEX = "\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*";
private static final String MULTI_DOT_REGEX = "\\s*\\.{3}\\s*";
private static final String APOSTROPHE_REGEX = "\\s*'\\s*";
private static final String FORMAT_CASE = "((?:^| )^\\w" + "|" + MULTI_DOT_REGEX + "\\w" + "|" + DOT_REGEX + "\\w)";

private static final String COMA_REPLACEMENT = ", ";
private static final String MULTI_DOT_REPLACEMENT = "... ";
private static final String DOT_REPLACEMENT = ".";
private static final String APOSTROPHE_REPLACEMENT = "'";

public static void main(String[] args){
    String buffer = "";
    buffer = SECOND_STRING.replaceAll(COMA_REGEX, COMA_REPLACEMENT);
    buffer = buffer.replaceAll(DOT_REGEX, DOT_REPLACEMENT);
    buffer = buffer.replaceAll(MULTI_DOT_REGEX, MULTI_DOT_REPLACEMENT);
    buffer = buffer.replaceAll(APOSTROPHE_REGEX, APOSTROPHE_REPLACEMENT);

    buffer = getFormatCaseString(buffer);
    System.out.println(buffer);
}

private static String getFormatCaseString(String targetString){
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(FORMAT_CASE).matcher(targetString);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()){
        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, matcher.group().toUpperCase());
    }
    matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Работает, если текст на латинице:

```
       String s = "about 90 percent of all children attend public school, which is free ... the other 10 percent go I private schools,Which often include religious education. `";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s[a-z]|,[A-Z]|\\s`|\\s\\.{3}\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()){
        String item = matcher.group();
        s = item.matches("\\.\\s[a-z]") ? s.replaceAll(item, item.toUpperCase()) :
                item.matches(",[A-Z]") ? s.replaceAll(item, item.substring(0,1).concat(" ").concat(item.substring(1,2).toLowerCase())) :
                        item.matches("\\s`") ? s.replaceAll(item, "") :
                                item.matches("\\s\\.{3}\\s") ? s.replaceAll("\\s\\.{3}\\s", "... ") : "";
    }

    s = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
```

> About 90 percent of all children attend public school, which is
>   free... the other 10 percent go I private schools, which often include
>   religious education.

Comment: Перед многоточием символ пробела остался.

Comment: А сами не хотите поработать над этим?

Comment: я добавил вариант с многоточием

Comment: что бы разобраться скопировал ваш код и собрал, получил следующее: 
About 90 percent of... children attend public school, which is free... the other 10 percent go I private schools, which often include religious education.

Comment: да. странно. не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: заменил item на регулярку - отработало корректно. Кажется я понял. item - это конкретный текст, а не регулярка и  в последнем случае - это не экранированное многоточие распознается методом replaceAll как регулярка